# Which regexp would find my datetime format?

Tags: regex, bash

I created a regexp for a date with time, formatted like this:

25.06.19 / 16:30

I created the following regexp:

```
^[0-9]{2}\.[0-9]{2}\.[0-9]{4}\s.\/\s.[0-9]{2}\:[0-9]{2}$
```

The result should deliver the above match, but it doesn't. Can you help me fix my regexp?

Comment: yeah thank you very much

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your year can consist of two or four digits, use

```
regex='^[0-9]{2}\.[0-9]{2}\.[0-9]{2}([0-9]{2})?[[:space:]]*/[[:space:]]*[0-9]{2}:[0-9]{2}$'
#                                   ^^^^^^^^^^^
```

[Bash demo](https://ideone.com/8pk2C4):

```
s="25.06.19 / 16:30"
regex='^[0-9]{2}\.[0-9]{2}\.[0-9]{2}([0-9]{2})?[[:space:]]*/[[:space:]]*[0-9]{2}:[0-9]{2}$'
if [[ "$s" =~ $regex ]]; then
  echo "Matched!"
fi;
```

Note I also replaced `\s` with `[[:space:]]` that should have wider support in Bash, and `/` does not need escaping as there are no regex delimiters here, and `/` is not a special regex metacharacter. Besides, the dots in `\s.\/\s.`  are suspicious, I understand you wanted to match any 0 or more whitespaces, so I replaced `.` with `*`.